# HTML parsing how to remove tags, attributes in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-parsing

HTML parsing how to remove tags, attributes in mysql database

```
 preg_match("/<td id=\"enrolment_number\".*td>/", $page, $eno);   
    $e_no=$eno[0];
    $e_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$e_no);
    preg_match_all("/<p>(.*)<\/p>/", $page, $matches);    
    $nm=$matches[0][0];    
    $mob=$matches[0][4];    
    $sql= "INSERT INTO `leads` (`S.No`, `Enrolment_No`, `Enrolment_TimeStamp`, `Aadhaar_No`, `Name`, `Mobile`, `Address`, `City`, `District`, `State`, `Pincode`, `Remarks`) VALUES (NULL, '$e_no', '$e_dt', '$a_no', '$nm', '$mob', '$add', '$cit', '$dis', '$state', '$pin', '')";
```

Comment: Saved in mysql like this. I want to save the data without TAGS, ATTRIBUTES ONLY VALUE REAL ESCAPE STRING IS NOT WORKING.
<td id="enrolment_number">0000/00138/59364</td>
<td id="enrolment_date">18/02/2014 16:45:29</td>
<td id="aadhar_no">430419478922</td>
<p>Jahir Mondal</p>
<p>8609607
<p>House No. - N0088, Rajkuthi,</p><p>Krishna Baza...
<p>Memari (m)</p>
<p>Barddhaman</p>
<p>West Bengal</p>
<p>713

Comment: use strip_tags("your html content"), it will give content without tags

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip_tags` function in php,

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] );
```

where `$allowable_tags` is optional, in which you can pass allowable tags,

For more info check it out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php